# skip video preview in uiimagecontroiller

Tags: ios, swift, video, uiimagepickercontroller, preview

I am using UIImagePickerController to allow my user to select a video from the photo library.
When the UIImagePickerController is initially displayed, it shows thumbnails for the various movies that have been recorded.
Once the user selects a movie, it displays a "preview" view which allows them to playback and potentially edit the selected movie.
Is there any way to avoid displaying this view and instead return the movie that was selected on the thumbnail screen?